# Error - Getting Unable to start AR tracking Please check that you have a camera connected error

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, artoolkit, jsartoolkit

I am not sure which repo is correct place to log this bug -
Hello,

I have just started development in AR / VR category and using ARToolkit with Unity. I created the most simple AR tracker with hiro.
Whenever I run the projet it gets stuck at above title error -

[image]

And this is the console details the errors ones -

```
ARController (native): [error]ARWrapper::ARToolKitVideoSource::open2(): error-failed to load camera parameters camera_para.dat, calling close(), exiting returning false
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ARController:Log(String) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:1656)
ARNativePlugin:arwStartRunningB(String, Byte[], Int32, Single, Single)
PluginFunctions:arwStartRunningB(String, Byte[], Int32, Single, Single) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/PluginFunctions.cs:114)
ARController:StartAR() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:607)
ARController:Start() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:393)

ARController (native): [info]Closing ARToolKit video.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ARController:Log(String) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:1656)
ARNativePlugin:arwStartRunningB(String, Byte[], Int32, Single, Single)
PluginFunctions:arwStartRunningB(String, Byte[], Int32, Single, Single) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/PluginFunctions.cs:114)
ARController:StartAR() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:607)
ARController:Start() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:393)


ARController (native): [error]ARController::startRunning(): Error: unable to open video source, exiting, returning false
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ARController:Log(String) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:1656)
ARNativePlugin:arwStartRunningB(String, Byte[], Int32, Single, Single)
PluginFunctions:arwStartRunningB(String, Byte[], Int32, Single, Single) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/PluginFunctions.cs:114)
ARController:StartAR() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:607)
ARController:Start() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:393)


ARController: Error starting running
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ARController:Log(String) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:1656)
ARController:StartAR() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:616)
ARController:Start() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:393)


AROrigin: Found 1 markers eligible to become base marker.
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ARController:Log(String) (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/ARController.cs:1656)
AROrigin:FindMarkers() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/AROrigin.cs:110)
AROrigin:Start() (at Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Scripts/AROrigin.cs:116)
```

Looks like the code is not able to find camera_para.dat. I find this in my AR folder, not sure if this is correct?

[image]

Comment: Can you run the example scene from here: ```Assets/ARToolKit5-Unity/Example Scenes/SimpleScene```?

Comment: Can you give me a screenshot of the ```ARToolKit/AR Controller/Video Options``` in the Unity Inspector window please

Comment: I am assuming you are either using a laptop front facing or a webcam. Are you positive that the drivers of the hardware are up to date an functioning properly? You could also try other software to confirm this, like `Skype`.

Comment: Hi guys. I am using l;aptop front facing, is it a problem? Also the sample app from AR toolkit did not work. Just for reference, exporting it to APK also did not work on my mobile phone

Comment: @KaushikRay In that case it's most likely the setup you have. What is the version of `Unity` you have and the `ARToolKit` as well? Try to upgrade to the latest possible. And is your front facing working (no its not a problem for AR)?

Comment: hi Thanks for the answer, but front facing is working and i used the latest version. This is sad as I wanted to use this but would now need to use Vuforia which is much more stable but expesive :(

Comment: It could be an issue with the streaming assets not finding the camera_para.dat file. Try using the latest dev build. For a lot of these issues the dev build tends to just take care of it. If its not that, this could stem from the ARController script not implementing the camera fast enough.